# dbeaver error: home/user/.ssh/id_rsa (Permission denied)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-keys, dbeaver

I generated id_rsa (private and pub) keys using ssh-key gen on a mac machine, there, I was able to setup dbeaver with the private key to authenticate to the remote server. I also uploaded that private key to a google drive and I'm able to use that same key to authenticate to the remote server from a script setup on google colab notebook. the key is password protected and that works fine on my mac and on that google colab script using the key stored in my google drive.

the problem is that when setting up dbeaver on another computer (ubuntu) to setup an ssh tunnel to connect to remote server instance. I get the following error: **home//.ssh (Permission denied)**, where  is my username on the ubuntu machine.

I basically downloaded the id_rsa stored in my google drive, set it under ~/.ssh/ and made sure that the id_rsa key file had 644 perms using chmod 644 id_rsa. I don´t think I need the public file but I also put it there and set the perms on that one to 600, as per the directions of [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder)
In dbeaver in my ubuntu machine I set the same configuration as I have it in my mac machine indicating where the private key file was being stored as shown on the image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

after I put together the question I run into this github thread that appears to indicate that if one where to use the dbeaver-ce version installed from snap (ubuntu app store) you needed to use a the snap > dbeaver> .ssh folder to store the ssh keys, so I created such folder and after relocating the keys there, the ssh tunnel worked!
source: [SSH Tunnel Permission denied #7640](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/7640#issuecomment-630526717)